# this.refs is not working on bootstrap modal giving null when trying to use with ReactDOM.findDOMNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am having problem when I am trying to access a modal ref when it is open.

The following is my wrapper class.

**ModalWrapper**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MyModal from './MyModal'
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export interface IModalWrapperProps {
}

export class ModalWrapper extends React.PureComponent<IModalWrapperProps, {}> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * EDITED HERE 
    */

    handlePrint = (refObj) => {
        //Getting the ref of the MyMoal component but when I trying to log the data key it is undefined
        console.log(refObj); //successfully logs the ref object of MyModal component.
        const refVal = refObj.data;
        const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(refVal);
        console.log(node) // logging null still
    }

    renderDivTag = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello Modal</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyModal id="test-modal" onPrint={this.handlePrint} showComponent={this.renderDivTag()} />
            <button onClick={() => showHelloModal('test-modal')} />
            )
    }
}
```

**MyModal Component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export interface IMyModalProps {
    modalID: string;
    id: string;
    showComponent: React.ComponentClass;
    onPrint: (ref) => void;
}

export class MyModalImpl extends React.PureComponent<IMyModalProps, {}> {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    /**
    * EDITED HERE 
    */

    refValue;

    handlePrint = () => { 
        return this.props.onPrint(this.refValue);
     }

    render() {
        if (this.props.modalID !== this.props.id) {
            return <div></div>;
        }
        return (
            <Modal className="print-preview-outer" show={true} >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Print Preview</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body className="print-preview">
                    <div 
                            /**
                            * EDITED HERE   
                            */

                        ref=((value) => this.refValue = value)
                        style={{ width: '597px', background: 'white', margin: 'auto' }}
                        id="print-preview"
                    >
                        {this.props.showComponent}
                    </div>
                </Modal.Body>
                <button onClick={this.handlePrint}>Print</button>
            </Modal >
        )
    }
}

export function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        modalID: state.get('modalID')
    }
};

export const MyModal = connect<{}, {}, IMyModalProps>(mapStateToProps)(MyModalImpl)
```

So when I am clicking the button the showHelloModal method sets a value on the key `modalID` and then I compare both the modal id and if both is equal then I show the modal.

Now what I am trying to do is I need the DOMNode of the MyModal component in my ModalWrapper Component to print that Hello Modal Word after the modal is displayed.

How can I get a reference to the DOM Node using the ref. If I am using the `document.getElementById('print-preview')` I am able to access the DOM Node of that modal but I want to use ref instead.

One more thing when I am loggin the `this.refs` inside my `ModalWrapper` Component I am getting an Object in the console as follow

[The console.log on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtKI9.png)

Any Help would be appericited.

Comment: Don't use string literals as refs instead use callback functions. Also refs are only visible inside the same component not across.

Comment: I suggest to use refs by callback function as documented here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

this.refs.data is used in ModalWrapper and defined in MyModalImpl. I suspect ModalWrapper can't see the refs value because it is defined in an another component.

Comment: I tried using the callback function also but I got null on that also.
I have updated the code to use the callback function but I am still getting null as node.

Comment: Yess the Modal is an another component but when It is being displayed it should be the child of the ModalWrapper component Idk if I am thinking wrong?\

Answer (score 0):

useRef hook will not work in modals as the component will mount but the jsx will not render until you make show prop to true.
useRef is asynchronous in nature thats why at the time of declaration it sets current to null but after you assign it to any element ref  got value of it.
But in case of modals the case is different. Here the elements are not registered instantly but after modal show prop is set to true

To solve this make the  modal's show prop always to true and make whole component to show/hide dynamically.
eg.

```
const Child=()=>{
const customRef=useRef(null);
return(
<Modal show={true}>
<Modal.Body>
<input ref={customRef} type="text"/>
</Modal.Body>
</Modal>
);
}
const Parent=()=>{
const [show,setShow]=useState=(false)
return(
<>
<button onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>Show/Hide Popup</button>
{
show?<Child/>:null
}
</>
)
}
```

this will surely solve your problem with using useRef in Modal Popup